# \org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-xjc\2.3.2\jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar!\META-INF\versions\9" is not a valid file name: {1}: Invalid file path ->

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have a Maven 3 build issue. Maven is

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: D:\Java\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 11.0.15, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: D:\Java\jdk-11.0.15
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

And the project that fails has this part, related to the failure:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-beeline</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>com.openpayment.provider.beeline.model</packageName>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/resources/schema/beeline.xsd</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!--hack https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin/issues/43-->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>${jaxb-xjc.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
                    <version>${jakarta.activation.property}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the fail is:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.403 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-09T19:21:09+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.4:xjc (xjc-beeline) on project beeline-provider-impl: "file:\D:\m2repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-xjc\2.3.2\jaxb-xjc-2.3.2.jar!\META-INF\versions\9" is not a valid file name: {1}: Invalid file path -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :beeline-provider-impl
```

What could be the reason of the fail?